# Maximum Cardinality Intersection of Every Pair of Equal-Size Sets

Tags: algorithm, optimization, set, set-intersection

We have N sets, each having N integers.

We take every pair of sets, and find their intersection set, S.

Now, we are interested to find the cardinality of the intersection set S that has maximum cardinality.

---

**Example**

For example, let N be 4 and we have 4 sets each of 4 elements:

A= {1,2,5,6}, B= {2,5,7,6}, C= {3,4,2,6}, D= {1,4,7,8}

Now we take pairwise intersection of these sets and an intersection set having maximum cardinality= {2,5,6}

So, we return 3.

---

A brute force solution can be done with *Θ(N<sup>3</sup>)* time. Can we do it more efficiently with an other method ?

Answer (score 2):

The following can reduce the running time if:

1. There is some *α > 0* such that (for fixed *α* and increasing *n*), there are two sets with at least an *α* fraction of overlap.
2. Many pairs are disjoint or nearly disjoint (made more precise later).
3. You are willing to use a high-probability Monte-Carlo algorithm (with probability of error decreasing with *n*).

Suppose you first transform each set into a hash table. This takes (expected) *Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)* time. Now for each pair of sets (i.e., an *n<sup>2</sup>* loop), select *√n*  random elements from the first set, and count the number of hits in the second set (expected  *O(√ n)* time).

By a combination of the [multiplicative Chernoff bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Multiplicative_form_.28relative_error.29) and the [union bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality), you can retain only pairs for which the number of hits was at least *1/2 α √ n*.

So, with high probability, you can narrow down *n<sup>2</sup>* pairs to some *β n<sup>2</sup>* pairs, with time only *O(n<sup>2.5</sup>)*. From here on continue with brute force. This is either useful or not depending on how *β* grows as a function as *n*.